# Photos library has inconsistencies

Tags: photos

[image]I am new to SE, so I apologize for possible duplicates.

I have a problem with my Photos library. It works fine on my iPhone and my iPad, but when I try to open it on my MacBook Pro (with macOS Mojave), I get a warning saying that the library has inconsistencies and needs to be repaired, but when I click the “ Repair” button, nothing happens.

I tried to fix the problem by quitting Photos (and I had to do the Force quit because it would quit otherwise) and reopening it while holding the option and command keys. Some repair process started, but it stopped after reaching 5% (whatever that means). All in all, I cannot open my Photo library and I cannot repair it. Does anybody have a suggestion as to how to fix it?

Comment: Quitting the repair process is a bad idea. How long did you wait, how big is the library and what specs does your Mac have? Is your Mac Photos library the same (i.e. same media) as your iPhone/iPad library?

Comment: I waited for a couple of minutes, but nothing was happening, so I quit. Also, the library is rather large (~40 GB) and it is the same as on my other devices. As for my MacBook, it is a MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports) with 2,3 GHz Intel Core i5 and 8 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3. The Photos library is stored on an external drive, though.

Comment: If your library is 50mb that should not happen, but for big libraries it can take **much** longer than a couple of minutes. Also, the loading bar is not linear at all. Just because it takes longer at the 5% mark, does not mean that will scale over the whole process! 40GB isn't that large, but still I suggest wait longer. Maybe your external drive is bottlenecking performance as well

Comment: Also, if you have the exact same library on your iPhone/iPad you could create a new empty library on the mac and import the files from your device. That would probably involve some new organizing though...

Comment: Repair and wait for at least half an hour as it takes time for the first repair.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I did as you suggested, but it didn't work. After reaching the 5%, the repair process stops and the "library has inconsistencies and needs to be repaired" message window pops up again. Hitting the Repair button doesn't help.

Comment: Ok it should not show that pop-up again... But how are you so sure that it **stops** at 5%? As I said, it might take **much** more time to reach 6% than it takes from 0-5%...

Comment: There is a progress bar which stops at 5% at which point the pop up window with the repair warning appears.

Comment: I added a picture to my question with a screenshot.

Comment: Lets chat about this: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104366/photos-library-repair

Comment: Thanks, but apparently I don&#8220;t have sufficient reputation (11 instead of 20)… Sorry.

Comment: Shoot... can you maybe try to earn that reputation?